# Malt parser, iterate over parsed tree in java

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to extract the tree dependencies from a Malt ConcurrentMaltParserModel. I iterate over the edges like:

```
SortedSet<ConcurrentDependencyEdge> edges = graph.getEdges();
for (ConcurrentDependencyEdge e : edges) {
      //here I would need to extract the dependency type
}
```

I thought I could extract the dependency type in a similar way as StanfordParser, but unfortunately I cant figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First obtain a [`SemanticGraph`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html) object (e.g. by retrieving the value of a `BasicDependenciesAnnotation` in the CoreNLP pipeline, or by parsing directly with Stanford Parser). I can elaborate on this more if necessary.

The `SemanticGraph` provides a simple edge iterable for processing independent graph edges. (See the [`SemanticGraphEdge`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraphEdge.html) class. Also, note that `SemanticGraphEdge.getRelation` returns a [`GrammaticalRelation`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/GrammaticalRelation.html) instance.)

```
SemanticGraph sg = ....
for (SemanticGraphEdge edge : sg.getEdgesIterable()) {
  int headIndex = edge.getGovernor().index();
  int depIndex = edge.getDependent().index();
  String label = edge.getRelation().getShortName();

  System.out.printf("%d %d %s%n", headIndex, depIndex, label);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question is: how do I transform the output of Malt to Stanford Parser. I already have an experience with Stanford, but not with Malt. As a partial solution, I read directly from CoNLL output. Is there any method that I can use in Stanford to read the CoNLL version produced by Malt? Thank you

Comment: There is no unified method to read CoNLL-X data at the moment, unfortunately. We have an [internal method in the NN dependency parser](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/nndep/Util.java#L108) that might serve as a good template for doing this.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look. ;)